# R: undo ordering / unsort / switch back to initial order

Tags: r, sorting

Suppose I have a vector

`test<-c("a","b","c","d","e")`

I am changing the order using another vector of indexes (this is essential):

```
sortvect<-c(2,3,5,4,1)
test2<-test[sortvect]
```

After that I do some operations on `test2` and after that I want to switch back to initial order, having `sortvect`:

`test<-give_my_order_back(test2,sortvect)`

I have tried `test2[sortvect]` and `test2[rev(sortvect)]` but the solution is apparently different.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thank you! It seems that `test2[match(test,test2)]` did the trick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not that difficult. `match(test, test2)` will give you the index for reordering back.

```
test <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
sortvect <- c(2,3,5,4,1)
test2 <- test[sortvect]
sortback <- match(test, test2)
test2[sortback]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Comment: This won't work if values in `test2` have changed in between

Comment: @HubertL @ZheyuanLi  I did `match(c(1,2,3,4,5),sortvect)` for my purposes

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  I've just noticed that the approach with `match()` potentially gives bigger powers (however I don't need them at the moment): one can roll back the order at particular stage, e.g. if there were two orderings applied sequentially:  `sortvect1` and `sortvect2`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I think match is faster only on short vectors (when speed doesn't really matter). But try benchmarking large vectors, you will see order is faster.

Comment: @Slowpoke you can of course also use `order` to undo sequentially applied orderings using `order (sortvec2)` followed by `order (sortvec1)`

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively `order` can also do this quite simply

```
test2[order(sortvect)]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by dww, to reverse the ordering, just use `order` on the index you used for deordering:

```
test <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
sortvect <- c(2,3,5,4,1)
test2 <- test[sortvect]
test2[order(sortvect)]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

this allows you to go back to original order even if you modified the object in between:

```
test <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
sortvect <- c(2,3,5,4,1)
test2 <- test[sortvect]
set.seed(12)
test2 <- paste0(sample(c("a","b","c","d","e"), 5, replace = F),test2)
test2[order(sortvect)]
[1] "ba" "ab" "dc" "ed" "ce"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use rank() to compute the inverse permutation rather than
sort(sort(x)). its the same calculation.

```
> test[order(sortvect)][rank(sortvect)]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

in general the below identities hold:

```
set.seed(0)
x<-matrix(rnorm(100),1)

all(order(order(x))==rank(x))
all(x==x[order(x)][rank(x)])
```