# Fastest way to sort and desort rows of a matrix [r]

Tags: r

I have a matrix filled with somewhat random elements. I need every row sorted in decreasing order, then a function is called on the matrix, and finally the resulting matrix needs to be unsorted to the original order.

This is quickly accomplished vector-wise as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884250/r-undo-ordering-unsort-switch-back-to-initial-order), but what's the fastest way to do this to every row in a matrix? Right now I'm doing:

```
# Example matrix
m <- matrix(runif(100), nrow = 25, ncol = 4)

# Get the initial order by row
om <- t(apply(m, 1, order, decreasing = T))

sm <- m
for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
  sm[i, ] <- sm[i, om[i, ]]
}

# ** Operations performed on sm **

# Then unsort
for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
  sm[i, ] <- sm[i, order(om[i, ])]
}

# sm is now sorted by-row in the same order as m
```

Is there some way given `om` in the above to sort and unsort while avoiding the for loop or an apply function (both of which make this operation very slow for big m). Thanks!

Edit: There are pointers here:  [Fastest way to sort each row of a large matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506442/fastest-way-to-sort-each-row-of-a-large-matrix-in-r)
The operation is done inside a function that is already called using parallel, so this operation must be done using serial code.

Comment: Have you seen [Fastest way to sort each row of a large matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506442/fastest-way-to-sort-each-row-of-a-large-matrix-in-r) ?

Comment: @RonakShah thanks, yes I did. But that doesn't discuss the un-sorting of the matrix. I'll also edit my question to include that doing the operation in parallel isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Row-wise sorting seems to be straightforward. To get the original order back (un-sort) we need the row-wise *ranks* rather than their order. Thereafter, what works for column sorting in [*@Josh O'Brien's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11108851/6574038) we can adapt for rows.

Base R solution:

```
rr <- t(apply(m, 1, rank))  ## get initial RANKS by row
sm <- t(apply(m, 1, sort))  ## sort m

##  DOING STUFF HERE  ##

sm[] <- sm[cbind(as.vector(row(rr)), as.vector(rr))]  ## un-sort
all(m == sm)  ## check
# [1] TRUE
```

Seems to work.

In your linked answer, the `rowSort` function of the `Rfast` package stands out well in terms of performance, which may cover the sorting issue. Moreover there's also a `rowRanks` function that will cover our ranking issue. So we can avoid `apply`.

Let's try it out.

```
m[1:3, ]
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]        [,4]
# [1,] 0.9148060 0.5142118 0.3334272 0.719355838
# [2,] 0.9370754 0.3902035 0.3467482 0.007884739
# [3,] 0.2861395 0.9057381 0.3984854 0.375489965

library(Rfast)
rr <- rowRanks(m)  ## get initial RANKS by row
sm <- rowSort(m)   ## sort m
sm[1:3, ]  # check
#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.36106962 0.4112159 0.6262453 0.6311956
# [2,] 0.01405302 0.2171577 0.5459867 0.6836634
# [3,] 0.07196981 0.2165673 0.5739766 0.6737271

##  DOING STUFF HERE  ##

sm[] <- sm[cbind(as.vector(row(rr)), as.vector(rr))]  ## un-sort
all(sm == m)  ## check
# [1] TRUE
```

Dito.

### Benchmark

```
m.test <- matrix(runif(4e6), ncol = 4)
dim(m.test)
# [1] 1000000       4

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min       lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
#    Rfast   897.6286   910.91   956.6259   924.1914   986.1246   1048.058     3 a  
#    baseR 87931.2824 88004.73 95659.8671 88078.1737 99524.1594 110970.145     3   c
#  forloop 58927.7784 59434.54 60317.3903 59941.2930 61012.1963  62083.100     3  b
```

Not so bad!!

---

*Data/Code:*

```
set.seed(42)

m <- matrix(runif(100), nrow = 25, ncol = 4)

## benchmark
m.test <- matrix(runif(4e6), ncol = 4)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Rfast={
    rr <- rowRanks(m.test)
    sm <- rowSort(m.test)
    sm[] <- sm[cbind(as.vector(row(rr)), as.vector(rr))]},
  baseR={
    rr <- t(apply(m.test, 1, rank))
    sm <- t(apply(m.test, 1, sort))
    sm[] <- sm[cbind(as.vector(row(rr)), as.vector(rr))]
  },
  forloop={
    om <- t(apply(m.test, 1, order, decreasing = T))
    sm <- m.test
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m.test))) {
      sm[i, ] <- sm[i, om[i, ]]
    }
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m.test))) {
      sm[i, ] <- sm[i, order(om[i, ])]
    }
  }, times=3L
)
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. I didn't know about the Rfast package. I was hoping to do it using only base R, but it looks like the speedup from Rcpp is very large in comparison.

Comment: colSort and colRanks uses C++'s sort. Rcpp has a minor role in thise algorithms. Also check the parallel version of these functions. Way faster than sequential version.

Comment: I didn't notice that it was done using C++ sort, that's interesting. Does the C++ sort perform noticeably better than Rcpp's sort? Like I say in my question, however, doing these operations in parallel isn't a possibility.

Comment: Yes. C++'s Introsort is the heaviest and fastest sorting algorithm in this planet. At least for now.  If you don't mind I ask, why not parallel?

Comment: Thanks for the info Manos, the operation is done inside a function that is already called using parallel. There are no cores to spare for this operation, so making it parallel would just clobber the cache.